# User input insertion into DB through AJAX results in empty fields

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have a PHP script that does the insertion part as follows(I know, no PDO or mysqli, this is just for my personal testing):

```
<?php
  $user = $_POST['user'];
  $comments = $_POST['comment'];

  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db('localh',$con);

  $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO content (Title, Article)
    VALUES('$user', '$comments')");

  if(!$query){die(mysql_error());}

  mysql_close($con);
?>
```

If I use this script in a form action it will work fine, the input values will be added to the database.

Here's the form:

```
<form>
  <p>User: <input type="text" id="user" /></p>
  <p>Comment:<input type="text" id="comment" /></p>
  <input type="button" id="submit" onClick="insertData();" />
</form>
```

And the AJAX part, located between the head tags:

```
function insertData(){
  var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  var usr = document.getElementById("user").value;
  var cmnt = document.getElementById("comment").value;

  ajaxRequest.open("POST", "insert.php", true);
  ajaxRequest.send(usr, cmnt);
}
```

The result will be an empty row in the database. I don't know why that is, I'm clueless.

Comment: As long as you know, make sure you use it responsibly. I'm posting this comment for future visitors: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: not forgetting the major sqli vulnerability.

Comment: i wonder do people seriously read that notice.... I pray that they do.

Comment: @itachi: Well, that question has 966 views, the link itself has 160 clicks. So I'd say yes, people do read it. I've personally gotten positive feedback from OPs who learned from it.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Very good news. Indirectly stackoverflow is doing a favor for php.

Comment: i may be wrong here but shouldn't some header `ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` should be added? been ages since i used raw javascript for ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this is one of the only very specific cases where I actually recommend someone to use jQuery.

AJAX is probably the most ambiguously implemented feature. Each browser has its quirks regarding its implementation. jQuery can be used to iron out those cross-browser incompatibility.

**[jQuery `$.ajax` documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually sending the keys of your variables to your script:

```
ajaxRequest.send(usr, cmnt);
```

so your `$_POST` array will not contain `user` nor `comment`.

Although a switch to jQuery is probably a good idea, you can send your variables like:

```
var vars = encodeURI("user="+usr+"&comment="+cmnt);
ajaxRequest.send(vars);
```

But you would have to test that as I normally use jQuery for my ajax requests.

Comment: You also need to ensure that `usr` and `cmnt` are properly URL-encoded. This is another detail that jQuery will take care of for you (if you use it properly).

Answer (score 1):

Check if you recive in `$_POST` veriable `user` and `comments` data, just add in your php file something like that

> print_r($_POST); exit();

if you will havent them at server side check your `ajax`

if allright check your mysql query:

Comment: printing $_POST gives me "Array()", an empty array. Also I got "Undefined index" at both of my $user/$comment = $_POST['user']/['comment']; declarations in the php insert script.

Comment: It is mean, that you have mistakes in your ajax request, read documentation and look what you do wrong. And try to use jQuery ajax.